# NERD Commenter: Why it choose -- to comment a bash file?

Tags: gvim

One bash script is named without file extension, NERD Commenter works fine.

Another bash script name is aaa.sa. NERD Commenter is using -- to comment a line instead of #. File syntax highlight is also wrong.

How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`.sa` files are [detected by Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim#L1384-L1385) as [Sather](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/~sather) files.

You can check in Vim by issuing `:verbose set filetype?`.

If you want to have your own filetypes detected matching a particular pattern, please check the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8) (also other questions in the same section might be relevant for you).

Note, I find using the extension `sa` for bash files confusing and un-intuitive.

Comment: Since I don't use Sather file, I add below line to .vimrc to force .sa show as sh.  <br/> **`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sa set filetype=sh`**

Comment: Why would you use `sa` as extension for shell files?

Comment: It's not an extension, `sa` is stand-alone. And `.` is easier than `_` to type.